# ACF put a comma after the last repeater field value

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I've the following code

```
<?php if(have_rows('ore')):?>

        <?php while( have_rows('ore')): the_row();

                $start = get_sub_field('start');
                $end = get_sub_field('end');
        ?>

         <?php if( get_row_index() != 1 ){ echo '/'; }?>
               <?php echo $start;?> – <?php echo $end;?>    
    
    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Which outputs the two fields ("start" & "end") in this form: 12.00 – 13.00.
In case there are more than one, they’ll be displayed like this 12.00 – 13.00 / 15.40 – 16.00 and so on.

How can I put a comma after the last field? (--> 12.00 – 13.00 / 15.40 – 16.00, or even 12.00 – 13.00,)
(I guess I've to count the number of rows and when reaching the last one, put the comma ...)

Thanks

David

Comment: Hmm...If you need just comma at the end of your output, why you do not echo comma between `endwhile` and `endif`?

Comment: because it'll result in something like "12.00 – 13.00 / 15.40 – 16.00 ," with a space before the comma; but yes, another way to solve this could be to find a way to remove the space before the comma

Comment: Do not see where is this space come from in your code, but there are a lot of options you can try. For example, add a variable before while loop `$result = '';` Put everything inside this variable, like `$result .= $start . "-" . $end;` and of course `$result .= "/"`. After the while loop you can echo `trim($result) . ",";` (trim removes whitespaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating whitespace because of the blank line between the `echo $end` block and the `endwnile`, and because you're switching in and out of PHP which means everything between the `?>` and `<?php` - i.e. all of the whitespace - will get echoed out. (HTML then merges the blank lines and spaces into a single space for display.)

You can just do this a single PHP block to save switching in and out of PHP, which will prevent any extra whitespace getting echoed:

```php
<?php
if (have_rows('ore')) {
    while(have_rows('ore')) {
        the_row();

        $start = get_sub_field('start');
        $end = get_sub_field('end');

        if( get_row_index() != 1 ) {
            echo '/';
        }
        echo esc_html($start).' - '.esc_html($end);
    }
    echo ',';
}
?>
```

Note that I've also added [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) around the $start and $end values as you echo them. I might also check if these were present or not too before using them, unless you're positive they'll always have values.